# Call parent function from iframe with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe in which I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checksum').click(function(){
        window.parent.Clickarunsuministro($(this).val());
    })
})
```

When you click on `.checksum`, I want to call the function in the parent. It works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.

The error that appears is:

```
Permission denied to access property 'Clickarunsuministro'
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Is your iframe on the same domain as the parent, are you running the app locally

Comment: you can try to pass object to child window after init

Answer (score 0):

Iframes and the pages they run in are, generally, not allowed to directly interact for security reasons. Instead, you can use `message` events to send strings and json objects between the owning document and the iframe. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage for some details on the how and why.

Your code might work in Chrome and IE right now, but it's a safe bet that it soon won't, so better to future-proof your code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a jquery custom event

In iframe

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checksum').click(function(){
        $(window).trigger('clickarunsuministro', {data: $(this).val()})
    })
})
```

In parent

```
$('<frame-selector>').on('clickarunsuministro', function(event){
    console.log('data', event.data)
})
```